# Как воспроизвести gif "без фона" (PyQt5, Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, gif

Пытался отобразить видео на "прозрачном фоне", задумок было несколько, но остановился на использовании **QGraphicsVideoItem**, с его ItemIgnoresParentOpacity или ItemDoesntPropagateOpacityToChildren, и вроде бы всё просто, только вот написать ничего не получается...

нда... (где то в середине я окончательно запутался в документации, поэтому код не дописан, а переменные я решил убрать, для простоты чтения, всё равно в них нет смысла, ибо код не рабочий)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class SuperPlayer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__(self)

        self.gv = QGraphicsView()
        self.mp = QMediaPlayer()  # Передаёт поток на gvi
        self.gs = QGraphicsScene()  # Передаёт поток на gv

        # Передаёт поток на gs, с надстройкой о игнорировании
        # прозрачности родительских классов дочерними
        self.gvi = QGraphicsVideoItem()

        self.gvi.setMediaObject()
        self.gs.addItem()
        self.gv.setScene()
        self.mp.setVideoOutput()
        self.gvi.setOpacity()
        slef.gvi.ItemIgnoresParentOpacity(True)

        # Думал переслать видео поток на него
        # self.vw = QVideoWidget()
        # self.vw.setWindowOpacity()
        # self.vw.showFullScreen()

        self.mp.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("my.gif")))
        self.gv.showFullScreen()
        self.mp.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = SuperPlayer()
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Так видео или гифку? Видео без фона не будет (они ведь не бывают с прозрачностью, разве нет?). Если гифка будет с прозрачным фоном, то проблем не должно возникнуть

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы показать gif с прозрачным фоном на экране, можно убрать декорации окна и поместить QMovie в QLabel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Show animated gif with a transparent background on the screen."""
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QLabel()
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # transparent window
w.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

movie = QMovie('Beating_Heart.gif')
w.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()


# center
w.adjustSize()  # update w.rect() now
w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Запустив с [картинкой со стучащим сердцем](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Beating_Heart.gif), запись экрана может выглядеть как:

[image: beating heart screencast]

Answer (score 0):

[Пример с воспроизведением gif через QLabel](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ec258072f2f27f2e945c2471d6fcee952b29f405/pyqt__loading_gif/main__QMovie__QLabel.py).

Как видно по виджету с измененным фоном, если у гифки прозрачный фон, то проблем с фоном виджета не будет:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('loading_gif')

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(3):
            movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
            label_loading = QLabel()
            label_loading.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()

            label_loading.setFrameStyle(QLabel.Box)

            self.main_layout.addWidget(label_loading)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw_1 = Window()
    mw_1.show()

    mw_2 = Window()
    mw_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
    mw_2.show()

    app.exec()
```

Будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Пример с воспроизведением gif через QLabel на QGraphicsView](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/05c16debd2f9758ff4db1ee01426a7f3412cc958/pyqt__loading_gif/main__QMovie__QLabel__QGraphicsScene.py).

Как видно по виджету с измененным фоном, если у гифки прозрачный фон, а у самого виджета установлен атрибут `Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent`, то проблем с фоном виджета не будет:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsLinearLayout, QGraphicsWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('loading_gif')
        self.resize(250, 120)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        main_layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Horizontal)

        form = QGraphicsWidget()
        form.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.scene.addItem(form)

        for i in range(3):
            movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
            label_loading = QLabel()
            label_loading.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()

            label_loading.setFrameStyle(QLabel.Box)
            label_loading.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent)

            proxy_item = self.scene.addWidget(label_loading)
            main_layout.addItem(proxy_item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw_1 = Window()
    mw_1.show()

    mw_2 = Window()
    mw_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
    mw_2.show()

    app.exec()
```

Выглядеть виджет будет также как на первой гифке, только чуть больше размер окон

Answer (score 0):

**Ещё один неплохой вариант**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.movie_screen = QLabel(self)
        self.movie_screen.setGeometry(300, 50, 500, 500)
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.movie_screen.setWindowFlags(Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.movie_screen.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication([])
    app = Example()
    app.show()
    qApp.exec()
```