# Изменение дизайна окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, framelesswindowhint

Хочу создать окно приложения в *PyQt5* примерно как на картинке.

Как это можно воплотить? Вообще не понятно как менять стандартные иконки кнопок, лейбов и т.п.

И если можно подскажите литературу для изучения по этой теме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: pyqt позволяет без системных декораций окно показывать, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791289/23044). При этом вы можете свои элементы показывать как  угодно, применяя стили и/или themes, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48256772/4279).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QSpacerItem,
    QSizePolicy, QLabel, QApplication)


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
"""


class Dialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setObjectName('Custom_Dialog')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)

        self.initUi()

        # Добавить тень
        effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        effect.setBlurRadius(12)
        effect.setOffset(2, 2)
        effect.setColor(Qt.gray)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    def initUi(self):
        # Важно: этот widget используется в качестве фона и закругленных углов
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # Добавить пользовательский интерфейс в виджет
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.accept, objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h2>Hello, world!</h2>"), 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)                           

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(500, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.exec_()
    QTimer.singleShot(200, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]