# Как модернизировать заголовок главного окна приложения?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside2, framelesswindowhint

Хочу модернизировать заголовок окна приложения. 
Например, цвет заголовка и хочу добавить еще одну собственную кнопку.

Как это реализовать, чтобы НЕ было вечно такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys, os, time, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

# стиль
StyleSheet = """
/* Панель заголовка */
TitleBar {
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
/* Минимизировать кнопку `Максимальное выключение` Общий фон по умолчанию */
#buttonMinimum,#buttonMaximum,#buttonClose, #buttonMy {
    border: none;
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
/* Зависание */
#buttonMinimum:hover,#buttonMaximum:hover {
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
#buttonClose:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
#buttonMy:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;   /* rgb(232, 17, 35) */
}
/* Мышь удерживать */
#buttonMinimum:pressed,#buttonMaximum:pressed {
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
#buttonClose:pressed {
    color: white;
    background-color: #2a3440;
}
"""

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Window = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.Window.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    Win = Window()
    Win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**MainWindow.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(257, 60)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: Заголовок окна как и рамка рисуется оконным менеджером, поэтому Qt тут не поможет. Но можно у окна сказать FramelessWindowHint и вручную нарисовать заголовок окна, а также поддержать возможность перемещать за заголовок и менять размер через границы окна

Comment: Можно простой пример кода.

Comment: Мне хотя бы цвет поменять

Comment: связанный вопрос [Изменение дизайна окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851868/23044)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отличный пример демонстрации как это делается:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSignal

from FramelessWindow import FramelessWindow  


# Created on 2018年4月30日
# author: Irony
# site: https://github.com/892768447
# email: 892768447@qq.com
# file: Test
# description:
__Author__ = """By: Irony
QQ: 892768447
Email: 892768447@qq.com"""
__Copyright__ = 'Copyright (c) 2018 Irony'
__Version__ = 1.0


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        objectTitleBar = args[0].titleBar

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Кнопка', self))
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)    
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)    

        objectTitleBar.signalButtonMy.connect(self.onButtonMy)

    def onButtonMy(self):
        self.textEdit.append("Нажата `Своя Кнопка`!")


# стиль
StyleSheet = """
/* Панель заголовка */
TitleBar {
    background-color: rgb(54, 157, 180);
}
/* Минимизировать кнопку `Максимальное выключение` Общий фон по умолчанию */
#buttonMinimum,#buttonMaximum,#buttonClose, #buttonMy {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(54, 157, 180);
}
/* Зависание */
#buttonMinimum:hover,#buttonMaximum:hover {
    background-color: rgb(48, 141, 162);
}
#buttonClose:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(232, 17, 35);
}
#buttonMy:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;   /* rgb(232, 17, 35) */
}
/* Мышь удерживать */
#buttonMinimum:pressed,#buttonMaximum:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(44, 125, 144);
}
#buttonClose:pressed {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(161, 73, 92);
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Тестовая строка заголовка')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Qt.ico'))
    w.setWidget(MainWindow(w))          # Добавить свое окно
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

FramelessWindow.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, pyqtSignal, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFont, QEnterEvent, QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QPushButton)


# Created on 2018年4月30日
# author: Irony
# site: https://github.com/892768447
# email: 892768447@qq.com
# file: FramelessWindow
# description:
__Author__ = """By: Irony
QQ: 892768447
Email: 892768447@qq.com"""
__Copyright__ = 'Copyright (c) 2018 Irony'
__Version__ = 1.0


class TitleBar(QWidget):

    # Сигнал минимизации окна
    windowMinimumed = pyqtSignal()
    # увеличить максимальный сигнал окна
    windowMaximumed = pyqtSignal()
    # сигнал восстановления окна
    windowNormaled = pyqtSignal()
    # сигнал закрытия окна
    windowClosed = pyqtSignal()
    # Окно мобильных
    windowMoved = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    # Сигнал Своя Кнопка +++
    signalButtonMy = pyqtSignal()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Поддержка настройки фона qss
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.mPos     = None
        self.iconSize = 20                       # Размер значка по умолчанию

        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # макет
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # значок окна
        self.iconLabel = QLabel(self)
#         self.iconLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)

        # название окна
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.titleLabel.setMargin(2)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)

        # Средний телескопический бар  
        layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        # Использовать шрифты Webdings для отображения значков
        font = self.font() or QFont()
        font.setFamily('Webdings')


        # Своя Кнопка ++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
        self.buttonMy = QPushButton(
            '@', self, clicked=self.showButtonMy, font=font, objectName='buttonMy')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMy)


        # Свернуть кнопку
        self.buttonMinimum = QPushButton(
            '0', self, clicked=self.windowMinimumed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonMinimum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum)

        # Кнопка Max / restore
        self.buttonMaximum = QPushButton(
            '1', self, clicked=self.showMaximized, font=font, objectName='buttonMaximum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum)

        # Кнопка закрытия
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.windowClosed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonClose')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        # начальная высота
        self.setHeight()

    # +++ Вызывается по нажатию кнопки buttonMy
    def showButtonMy(self):  
        print("Своя Кнопка ")  
        self.signalButtonMy.emit()

    def showMaximized(self):
        if self.buttonMaximum.text() == '1':
            # Максимизировать
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('2')
            self.windowMaximumed.emit()
        else:  # Восстановить
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('1')
            self.windowNormaled.emit()

    def setHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
        # Задайте размер правой кнопки  ?
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMaximumSize(height, height)

        self.buttonMy.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMy.setMaximumSize(height, height)

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ Установить заголовок """
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)

    def setIcon(self, icon):
        """ настройки значокa """
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(self.iconSize, self.iconSize))

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установить размер значка """
        self.iconSize = size

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super(TitleBar, self).enterEvent(event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super(TitleBar, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        self.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        self.mPos = None
        event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            self.windowMoved.emit(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self.mPos))
        event.accept()


# Перечислить верхнюю левую, нижнюю правую и четыре неподвижные точки
Left, Top, Right, Bottom, LeftTop, RightTop, LeftBottom, RightBottom = range(8)


class FramelessWindow(QWidget):

    # Четыре периметра
    Margins = 5

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FramelessWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pressed  = False
        self.Direction = None

        # Фон прозрачный
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Нет границы
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # Отслеживание мыши
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # макет
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        # Зарезервировать границы для изменения размера окна без полей
        layout.setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)
        # Панель заголовка
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)

        # слот сигнала
        self.titleBar.windowMinimumed.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.titleBar.windowMaximumed.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.titleBar.windowNormaled.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.titleBar.windowClosed.connect(self.close)
        self.titleBar.windowMoved.connect(self.move)
        self.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setTitle)
        self.windowIconChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setIcon)

    def setTitleBarHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.titleBar.setHeight(height)

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установка размера значка """
        self.titleBar.setIconSize(size)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        """ Настройте свои собственные элементы управления """
        if hasattr(self, '_widget'):
            return
        self._widget = widget
        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self._widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self._widget.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self._widget.setPalette(palette)
        self._widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._widget)

    def move(self, pos):
        if self.windowState() == Qt.WindowMaximized or self.windowState() == Qt.WindowFullScreen:
            # Максимизировать или полноэкранный режим не допускается
            return
        super(FramelessWindow, self).move(pos)

    def showMaximized(self):
        """ Чтобы максимизировать, удалите верхнюю, нижнюю, левую и правую границы. 
            Если вы не удалите его, в пограничной области будут пробелы. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showMaximized()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def showNormal(self):
        """ Восстановить, сохранить верхнюю и нижнюю левую и правую границы, 
            иначе нет границы, которую нельзя отрегулировать """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showNormal()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ Фильтр событий, используемый для решения мыши в других элементах 
            управления и восстановления стандартного стиля мыши """
        if isinstance(event, QEnterEvent):
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        return super(FramelessWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """ Поскольку это полностью прозрачное фоновое окно, жесткая для поиска 
            граница с прозрачностью 1 рисуется в событии перерисовывания, чтобы отрегулировать размер окна. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1), 2 * self.Margins))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._mpos = event.pos()
            self._pressed = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._pressed = False
        self.Direction = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие перемещения мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        pos = event.pos()
        xPos, yPos = pos.x(), pos.y()
        wm, hm = self.width() - self.Margins, self.height() - self.Margins
        if self.isMaximized() or self.isFullScreen():
            self.Direction = None
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            return
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self._pressed:
            self._resizeWidget(pos)
            return
        if xPos <= self.Margins and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # Верхний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # Нижний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # верхний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif xPos <= self.Margins and hm <= yPos:
            # Нижний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif 0 <= xPos <= self.Margins and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Влево
            self.Direction = Left
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Право
            self.Direction = Right
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and 0 <= yPos <= self.Margins:
            # выше
            self.Direction = Top
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # ниже
            self.Direction = Bottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)

    def _resizeWidget(self, pos):
        """ Отрегулируйте размер окна """
        if self.Direction == None:
            return
        mpos = pos - self._mpos
        xPos, yPos = mpos.x(), mpos.y()
        geometry = self.geometry()
        x, y, w, h = geometry.x(), geometry.y(), geometry.width(), geometry.height()
        if self.Direction == LeftTop:          # Верхний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
        elif self.Direction == RightBottom:    # Нижний правый угол
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
        elif self.Direction == RightTop:       # верхний правый угол
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos.setX(pos.x())
        elif self.Direction == LeftBottom:     # Нижний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos.setY(pos.y())
        elif self.Direction == Left:            # Влево
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Right:           # Право
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Top:             # выше
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Bottom:          # ниже
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И вправду, отличный пример!

Comment: Ого! Спасибо большое. Буду изучать)

Comment: @Michael Shcherbakov если это вам поможет, не забудьте отметить ответ как полезный)

Comment: А как можно установить собственный значок на 'ButtonMy'?