# Добавить свои кнопки / виджеты на верхнюю панель окна Qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyside2

Есть ли какой-то простой способ добавить свои кнопки / виджеты на верхнюю панель окна как на примере на скрине (кнопка меню в старом Firefox)?

[image: Кнопка на верхней панели окна]

Или истинный путь только через:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint);
```

..и рисование своих рамок окна, верхней панели с управляющими кнопками и вот всё такое?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724802/widgets-in-window-title-qt

Comment: @AlexanderChernin  Спасибо, так и думал что простым способом без API оконного менеджера ОС нельзя, придётся своё рисовать.

Comment: Надо рисовать см. пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855760/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0/855884#855884