# Как кастомизировать шапку окна приложения определенным образом?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qss, framelesswindowhint

Мне нужно изменить визуальные характеристики шапки окна приложения. 
Шапкой я называю верхнюю часть рамки приложения, содержащую в себе кнопки

- **"свернуть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой ***1***),
- **"развернуть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой ***2***),
- **"свернуть в окно"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой ***3***) и
- **"закрыть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой ***4***).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот список необходимых изменений:

1. Я заметил, что шапка может именять свою высоту. При разворачивании окна на весь экран, значение высоты становится немного меньше обычного. Эта особенность испортит все мои планы, поэтому мне нужно задать **постоянное** значение высоты шапки - **20px**.
2. Необходимо изменить цвет шапки.
3. Как я писал выше, на шапке расположены четыре кнопки (одновременно только три). Каждая из них может находится в своем обычном состоянии и активном, когда на кнопку навели курсор мыши. Я хочу заменить текстуры всех кнопок в обоих состояниях на заготовленные изображения.

Новые текстуры для кнопки **"свернуть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **1**):

Обычное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новые текстуры для кнопки **"развернуть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **2**):

Обычное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новые текстуры для кнопки **"свернуть в окно"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **3**):

Обычное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новые текстуры для кнопки **"закрыть"** (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **4**):

Обычное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активное состояние - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Размеры заготовленных мною изображений - 30px * 20px. Мне необходимо, чтобы кнопки на шапке были абсолютно таких же размеров - **30px * 20px**.
5. Между кнопками не должно быть абсолютно никакого пространства. Они должны прижаться вплотную друг к другу, а самая правая из них должна вплотную прижаться к правому краю шапки. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. От иконки приложения (в левом углу) нужно избавиться.
7. Мое приложение может открывать окно выбора директории. Я бы хотел, чтобы вышеперечисленные изменения не затронули это окно.

Пожалуйста, скажите, как это можно сделать?

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet('background: #161719;')

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        box.addWidget(btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.resize(250, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Лучше задать логически разные вопросы отдельно. Например, цвет не связан с иконками, поэтому можно разбить на 2 вопроса. Человек, который будет позже искать "как изменить цвет" сможет найти вопрос про цвет, но вряд ли сможет найти этот

Comment: Да, понимаю это. Но будет ли удобно отвечающему человеку делать несколько ответов вместо одного и переписывать много раз одну и ту же QSS-таблицу?

Comment: Будет удобно ответить на более короткий вопрос более коротким кодом. Почему отвечающий на все вопросы должен быть один и тот же? А если есть одинаковые части в ответах, то скопировать их не проблема

Comment: Последнее время отвечающий на мои вопросы по PyQt только один. И мне очень не хочется тревожить его своими вопросами по четыре раза за день. Я бы хотел знать его мнение касательно этого

Comment: Есть причина закрытия "вопрос слишком общий, разбейте его на несколько вопросов". Пока сообщество не проголосовало за то, чтобы её убрать, мнение одного участника по этому вопросу не имеет значения. В любом случае, странно, если участник потревожится получением двойной репутации за 2 связанных вопроса, когда общие части можно скопировать

Comment: Меня мало волнует репутация. Я считаю наиболее главным удобство отвечающего, и потому предлагаю дождаться его мнения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам повезло, у меня есть все необходимое для вас:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindowStateChangeEvent, QFont, QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, \
    QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QDialog

#from CTitleBar import CTitleBar
class CTitleBar(QWidget):
    Radius = 38

    def __init__(self, *args, title='заглавие, название', **kwargs):
        super(CTitleBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()
        
        # Поддержка настройки фона
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.mPos = None
        # Найти родительский элемент управления self.parent() (или self)
        self._root = self.window()             
        self.labelTitle.setText(title)
        
        # Вам нужно скрыть кнопку свернуть или развернуть
        self.showMinimizeButton(self.isMinimizeable())
        self.showNormalButton(False)
        self.showMaximizeButton(self.isMaximizeable())

        # Связывающий сигнал
        # windowTitleChanged сигнал испускается при изменении заголовка окна 
        # с новым заголовком в качестве аргумента.
        self._root.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.buttonMinimum.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.buttonMaximum.clicked.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.buttonClose.clicked.connect(self._root.close)
        
        # Установите фильтр событий на родительский элемент управления (или на себя)
        self._root.installEventFilter(self)

    def showMinimized(self):
        self._root.showMinimized()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonMinimum, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def showNormal(self):
        ''' Восстанавливает виджет после того, как он был развернут или свернут. '''
        self._root.showNormal()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonMaximum, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def showMaximized(self):
        self._root.showMaximized()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonNormal, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def isMinimizeable(self):
        return self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

    def isMaximizeable(self):
        return self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)

    def isResizable(self):
        return self._root.minimumSize() != self._root.maximumSize()

    def showMinimizeButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку сворачивания """
        self.buttonMinimum.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetMinimum.setVisible(show)

    def showMaximizeButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку максимизации """
        self.buttonMaximum.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetMaximum.setVisible(show)

    def showNormalButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку восстановления """
        self.buttonNormal.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetNormal.setVisible(show)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(CTitleBar, self).showEvent(event)
        if not self.isResizable():
            self.showMaximizeButton(False)
            self.showNormalButton(False)
        else:
            self.showMaximizeButton(
                self.isMaximizeable() and not self._root.isMaximized())
            self.showNormalButton(self.isMaximizeable()
                                  and self._root.isMaximized())

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if isinstance(event, QWindowStateChangeEvent):
            if self._root.isVisible() and not self._root.isMinimized() and \
                    self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint):
                maximized = self._root.isMaximized()
                self.showMaximizeButton(not maximized)
                self.showNormalButton(maximized)
                
                if maximized:
                    self._oldMargins = self._root.layout().getContentsMargins()
                    self._root.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                else:
                    if hasattr(self, '_oldMargins'):
                        self._root.layout().setContentsMargins(*self._oldMargins)
        return super(CTitleBar, self).eventFilter(target, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        """ Дважды щелкните строку заголовка
        :param event:
        """
        if not self.isMaximizeable() or not self.isResizable():
            return
        if self._root.isMaximized():
            self._root.showNormal()
        else:
            self._root.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Координаты записи нажатия мышью
        :param event:
        """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь отпущена, удалить координаты
        :param event:
        """
        self.mPos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь двигает окно
        :param event:
        """
        if self._root.isMaximized():
            # Не двигается при максимизации
            return
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            pos = event.pos() - self.mPos
            self._root.move(self._root.pos() + pos)

    def testWindowFlags(self, windowFlags):
        """ Определите, есть ли у текущего окна флаги
        :param windowFlags:
        """
        return bool(self._root.windowFlags() & windowFlags)

    def setWindowTitle(self, title):
        """ Установка заголовка
        :param title:
        """
        self.labelTitle.setText(title)

    def setupUi(self):
        """ Создать пользовательский интерфейс """
        self.setMinimumSize(0, self.Radius)
        self.setMaximumSize(0xFFFFFF, self.Radius)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        for name in ('widgetMinimum', 'widgetMaximum', 'widgetNormal', 'widgetClose'):
            widget = QWidget(self)
            widget.setMinimumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            widget.setMaximumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            widget.setObjectName('CTitleBar_%s' % name)
            setattr(self, name, widget)
            layout.addWidget(widget)
            
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))
            
        # Название
        self.labelTitle = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelTitle.setObjectName('CTitleBar_labelTitle')
        layout.addWidget(self.labelTitle)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))
            
        # Свернуть, развернуть, восстановить, кнопкa закрыть 
        for name, text in (('buttonMinimum', '0'), ('buttonMaximum', '1'),
                           ('buttonNormal', '2'), ('buttonClose', 'r')):
            button = QPushButton(text, self, font=QFont('Webdings'))
            button.setMinimumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            button.setMaximumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            button.setObjectName('CTitleBar_%s' % name)
            setattr(self, name, button)
            layout.addWidget(button)


class TestCTitleBarBase:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestCTitleBarBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(500, 400)
        
        # Установите прозрачность фона
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        
        # Установите без границ
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        # Добавить пользовательскую строку заголовка
        layout.addWidget(CTitleBar(self, title='Custom TitleBar.'))
        
        # нижний Widget
        self.widget = QWidget(self, objectName='bottomWidget')
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # это ваш код :)
        box = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        btn = QPushButton('Button')
        box.addWidget(btn)        


class TestCTitleBarWidget(QWidget, TestCTitleBarBase):
    pass


# стиль строки заголовка
Style = """
/* Цвет строки заголовка */
CTitleBar {
    background: rgb(65, 148, 216);
}
/* Окно заголовка закруглено */
CTitleBar {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius:  10px;
}
#CTitleBar_buttonClose {
    /*  Вам нужно принять во внимание (закруглить) кнопку закрытия на правой стороне */
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* Нижние закругленные углы и фон */
#bottomWidget {
    background: white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

/*  Свернуть, развернуть, кнопка восстановления  */
CTitleBar > QPushButton {
    background: transparent;
}
CTitleBar > QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 30);
}
CTitleBar > QPushButton:pressed {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 60);
}

/*  Кнопка закрытия  */
#CTitleBar_buttonClose:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(232, 17, 35);
}
#CTitleBar_buttonClose:pressed {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(165, 69, 106);
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    import cgitb
    sys.excepthook = cgitb.enable(1, None, 5, '')
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Style)
    w = TestCTitleBarWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Главное окно')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Я думал все будет гораздо проще, попытаюсь подогнать код под свои нужды. Мы с еще одним пользователем сайта начали диалог в комментариях под моим вопросом. Я бы хотел знать вашу точку зрения - мне лучше задавать один крупный вопрос или несколько маленьких?

Comment: @MAXIM045 можно и проще :), но я вам предоставил универсальную вещь. Да это немного сложно, но это того стоит. Я не очень читаю дебаты в комментариях. В вашем случаи, считаю, что вопрос задан правильно - комплексно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Пожалуйста, говорите мне, если я что-то делаю не так. Мне очень важно ваше мнение

Comment: @MAXIM045 пожалуйста.

Comment: Только сейчас смог посмотреть работу кода. Боюсь, мне придется забыть о кастомизации шапки окна. Я думал, что все мною перечисленное можно будет настроить в таблице стиля, но это оказалось совсем не так. И даже такой крупный код не может полностью повторить поведение стандартного окна, что для меня, к сожалению, критично :(

Comment: @MAXIM045   по другому никак, почитайте комментарии:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855760/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0/855884#855884