# Как кастомизировать шапку в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt

Была похожая [тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178951/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC?newreg=b55708464fc249b496bf8072f4c100b4), но мне бы хотелось заменить весь этот большой код, тем чтобы в Qt Designer как-то можно было-бы кастомить как раз шапку... Возможно такое есть. Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: только скрывать системную и самостоятельно рисовать. За тайтлбар отвечает система

Comment: А как её скрыть?

Comment: в примере все есть self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)