Как изменить цвет верхней полоски в PyQt5?
Всем здравствуйте. Хотел бы задаться вопросом: Как изменить цвет верхней полоски в PyQt5?

Вот это. А так - нужно для темной темы :)

Отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178951/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc/1178977#1178977 на ваш вопрос ?

Спасибо, но я бы хотел просто сменить цвет если так можно

Егор Абрамович, пожалуйста. Да вам надо самостоятельно написать окно окно без полей (Qt.FramelessWindowHint).
