# Функция изменения размеров модифицированного окна курсором и движение окна по экрану за титульный бар

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsizegrip, mousemoveevent, eventfilter

Есть пример, по которому я пытаюсь изучить функцию изменения размера окна пользователем. Также в этом примере окно перемещается по экрану с зажатым на нём курсором на титульном баре. Если на этом окне зажать **ЛКМ** на фреймах контента, окно не движется, что мне и нужно.

Путём некоторых корректировок своего кода за счёт примера, я добиваюсь подобного результата, но есть подозрение, что код получается перегруженным и всё можно сделать проще.

Как мне можно реализовать два этих действия буквально в двух функциях? 
Гуглил, что означают методы из примера в официальной документации, но понимание не всегда приходит.

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.clicks = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.resize(1200, 700)
        # Скрытие стандартной шапки (Без границ)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # Прозрачность окна (WA_TranslucentBackground - прозрачный фон)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Прозрачность
        # self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)
        # Появление виджета в месте курсора
        # self.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.offset = None

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)
        # self.left_bar.setLineWidth(3) # Понятия не имею что это, тени нет в любом случае


# title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)

# min_button
        self.min_button = QPushButton()
        self.min_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-minus.png')))
        self.min_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.min_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.min_button.clicked.connect(self.turn_window)

# max_button
        self.max_button = QPushButton()
        self.max_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-fullscreen.png')))
        self.max_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.max_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.max_button.clicked.connect(self.expand_window)

# close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-power-standby.png')))
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

# menu_button
        self.menu_button = QPushButton()
        self.menu_button.setText("")
        self.menu_button.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-menu.png')))
        self.menu_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.menu_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle)

# page_1_button
        self.page_1_button = QPushButton()
        self.page_1_button.setText("")
        self.page_1_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-mood-very-good.png')))
        self.page_1_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

        self.chek_activ_1 = QFrame()
        self.chek_activ_1.setMaximumWidth(10)
        # self.chek_activ_1.setMinimumWidth(5)
        self.chek_activ_1.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# page_2_button
        self.page_2_button = QPushButton()
        self.page_2_button.setText("")
        self.page_2_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-mood-very-bad.png')))
        self.page_2_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

        self.chek_activ_2 = QFrame()
        self.chek_activ_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.chek_activ_2.setMaximumWidth(0)
        # self.chek_activ_2.setMinimumWidth(5)
        self.chek_activ_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.min_button, 0, 1)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.max_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.layout_menu_0 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_0.addWidget(self.menu_button)
        self.layout_menu_0.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_0.setSpacing(0)

        self.layout_menu_1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_1.addWidget(self.chek_activ_1)
        self.layout_menu_1.addWidget(self.page_1_button)
        self.layout_menu_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_1.setSpacing(0)

        self.layout_menu_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_2.addWidget(self.chek_activ_2)
        self.layout_menu_2.addWidget(self.page_2_button)
        self.layout_menu_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_0)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_1)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_2)
        self.vbox_1.addStretch()
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.content)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def turn_window(self):
        self.showMinimized()

    def expand_window(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.max_button.setIcon(
                QIcon("icons/Apagar/cil-fullscreen.png"))
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.max_button.setIcon(
                QIcon("icons/Apagar/cil-fullscreen-exit.png"))
            self.showMaximized()
            self.right_bar.setStyleSheet('''''')

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Координаты записи нажатия мышью
        :param event:
        """
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.offset = event.pos()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь двигает окно
        :param event:
        """
        if self.isMaximized():
            # Не двигается при максимизации
            return
        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.offset)
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь отпущена, удалить координаты
        :param event:
        """
        self.offset = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def toggle(self):
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.left_bar, b"minimumWidth")
        self.animation.setDuration(900)
        if self.left_bar.width() == 50:
            self.animation.setStartValue(50)
            self.animation.setEndValue(280)
            self.page_1_button.setText("Page 1")
            self.page_1_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Noimg.png')))
            self.page_2_button.setText("Page 2")
            self.page_2_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Noimg.png')))
        else:
            self.animation.setStartValue(280)
            self.animation.setEndValue(50)
            self.page_1_button.setText("")
            self.page_1_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-mood-very-good.png')))
            self.page_2_button.setText("")
            self.page_2_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-mood-very-bad.png')))

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutCubic)
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[**Код взятого мной примера**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1252882/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-title-bar-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-pyqt5-%D0%B2-qt-designer/1253045#1253045): (хотелось бы понять для чего функции `showEvent` и `eventFilter` в классе `CTitleBar`)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QImage, QMouseEvent, QPixmap, QWindowStateChangeEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("*{\n"
                                 "   font: 19pt \"Arial\";\n"
                                 "   color: #fff;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "QWidget{\n"
                                 "    background-color: #9B9B9A;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 0px;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#practical_btn,\n"
                                 "#settings_btn,\n"
                                 "#achiev_btn{\n"
                                 "    background-color: #E88327;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#state_btn{\n"
                                 "    background-color: #FFAA5C;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#achiev_btn:hover,\n"
                                 "#practical_btn:hover,\n"
                                 "#settings_btn:hover,\n"
                                 "#state_btn:hover{\n"
                                 "    background-color: #FFAA5C;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#edit_students,\n"
                                 "#edit_streams\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 "    image: url(images/okV.png);\n"
                                 "    border: none;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#table,\n"
                                 "#streams\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 "    background-color: #E88327;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "#btn_close:hover,\n"
                                 "#btn_min:hover,\n"
                                 "#btn_max:hover\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 "    background-color:#ccc;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 0px;\n"
                                 "}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.streams = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.streams.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 256, 681))
        self.streams.setStyleSheet("")
        self.streams.setObjectName("streams")
        self.edit_streams = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.edit_streams.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(195, 137, 18, 18))
        self.edit_streams.setCursor(
            QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit_streams.setStyleSheet("")
        self.edit_streams.setText("")
        self.edit_streams.setObjectName("edit_streams")
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 170, 1111, 681))
        self.table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.table.setObjectName("table")
        self.table.setColumnCount(0)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.edit_students = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.edit_students.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(945, 142, 18, 18))
        self.edit_students.setCursor(
            QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit_students.setStyleSheet("")
        self.edit_students.setText("")
        self.edit_students.setObjectName("edit_students")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 135, 111, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 135, 81, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.achiev_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.achiev_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.achiev_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 50, 221, 50))
        self.achiev_btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.achiev_btn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.achiev_btn.setObjectName("achiev_btn")
        self.state_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.state_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 221, 50))
        self.state_btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.state_btn.setObjectName("state_btn")
        self.practical_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.practical_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 221, 50))
        self.practical_btn.setCursor(
            QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.practical_btn.setObjectName("practical_btn")
        self.settings_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.settings_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 50, 221, 50))
        self.settings_btn.setCursor(
            QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.settings_btn.setObjectName("settings_btn")

        '''
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1441, 41))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.btn_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1310, 10, 75, 23))
        self.btn_close.setObjectName("btn_close")
        self.btn_max = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn_max.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1200, 10, 75, 23))
        self.btn_max.setObjectName("btn_max")
        self.btn_min = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn_min.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 10, 75, 23))
        self.btn_min.setObjectName("btn_min")
        '''

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1440, 34))
        self.menubar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "студенты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "потоки"))

        self.achiev_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "достижения"))
        self.state_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ведомость"))
        self.practical_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "практические"))
        self.settings_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "настройки"))

#        self.btn_close.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
#        self.btn_max.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
#        self.btn_min.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        layout_maim = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        lay_h = QHBoxLayout()
        lay_h.addWidget(self.state_btn)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.achiev_btn)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.practical_btn)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.settings_btn)
        layout_maim.addLayout(lay_h)

        lay_h = QHBoxLayout()
        lay_h.addStretch(0)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.label)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.edit_streams)
        lay_h.addStretch(2)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.label_2)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.edit_students)
        lay_h.addStretch(2)
        layout_maim.addLayout(lay_h)

        lay_h = QHBoxLayout()
        lay_h.addWidget(self.streams, 2)
        lay_h.addWidget(self.table, 3)
        layout_maim.addLayout(lay_h)

        labels = ("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3",
                  "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7")
        self.streams.addItems(labels)

        self.table.setRowCount(7)
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'])
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(5):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item {}-{}".format(i, j))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.table.setItem(i, j, item)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class CTitleBar(QWidget):
    Radius = 38

    def __init__(self, *args, title='заглавие, название', **kwargs):
        super(CTitleBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()

        # Поддержка настройки фона
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.mPos = None
        # Найти родительский элемент управления self.parent() (или self)
        self._root = self.window()
        self.labelTitle.setText(title)

        # Вам нужно скрыть кнопку свернуть или развернуть
        self.showMinimizeButton(self.isMinimizeable())
        self.showNormalButton(False)
        self.showMaximizeButton(self.isMaximizeable())

        # Связывающий сигнал
        # windowTitleChanged сигнал испускается при изменении заголовка окна
        # с новым заголовком в качестве аргумента.
        self._root.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.buttonMinimum.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.buttonMaximum.clicked.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.buttonClose.clicked.connect(self._root.close)

        # Установите фильтр событий на родительский элемент управления (или на себя)
        self._root.installEventFilter(self)

    def showMinimized(self):
        self._root.showMinimized()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonMinimum, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def showNormal(self):
        ''' Восстанавливает виджет после того, как он был развернут или свернут. '''
        self._root.showNormal()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonMaximum, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def showMaximized(self):
        self._root.showMaximized()
        QApplication.sendEvent(self.buttonNormal, QMouseEvent(
            QMouseEvent.Leave, QPointF(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier))

    def isMinimizeable(self):
        return self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

    def isMaximizeable(self):
        return self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)

    def isResizable(self):
        return self._root.minimumSize() != self._root.maximumSize()

    def showMinimizeButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку сворачивания """
        self.buttonMinimum.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetMinimum.setVisible(show)

    def showMaximizeButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку максимизации """
        self.buttonMaximum.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetMaximum.setVisible(show)

    def showNormalButton(self, show=True):
        """ Показать скрытую кнопку восстановления """
        self.buttonNormal.setVisible(show)
        self.widgetNormal.setVisible(show)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(CTitleBar, self).showEvent(event)
        if not self.isResizable():
            self.showMaximizeButton(False)
            self.showNormalButton(False)
        else:
            self.showMaximizeButton(
                self.isMaximizeable() and not self._root.isMaximized())
            self.showNormalButton(self.isMaximizeable()
                                  and self._root.isMaximized())

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if isinstance(event, QWindowStateChangeEvent):
            if self._root.isVisible() and not self._root.isMinimized() and \
                    self.testWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint):
                maximized = self._root.isMaximized()
                self.showMaximizeButton(not maximized)
                self.showNormalButton(maximized)

                if maximized:
                    self._oldMargins = self._root.layout().getContentsMargins()
                    self._root.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                else:
                    if hasattr(self, '_oldMargins'):
                        self._root.layout().setContentsMargins(*self._oldMargins)
        return super(CTitleBar, self).eventFilter(target, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        """ Дважды щелкните строку заголовка
        :param event:
        """
        if not self.isMaximizeable() or not self.isResizable():
            return
        if self._root.isMaximized():
            self._root.showNormal()
        else:
            self._root.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Координаты записи нажатия мышью
        :param event:
        """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь отпущена, удалить координаты
        :param event:
        """
        self.mPos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь двигает окно
        :param event:
        """
        if self._root.isMaximized():
            # Не двигается при максимизации
            return
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            pos = event.pos() - self.mPos
            self._root.move(self._root.pos() + pos)

    def testWindowFlags(self, windowFlags):
        """ Определите, есть ли у текущего окна флаги
        :param windowFlags:
        """
        return bool(self._root.windowFlags() & windowFlags)

    def setWindowTitle(self, title):
        """ Установка заголовка
        :param title:
        """
        self.labelTitle.setText(title)

    def setupUi(self):
        """ Создать пользовательский интерфейс """
        self.setMinimumSize(0, self.Radius)
        self.setMaximumSize(0xFFFFFF, self.Radius)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        for name in ('widgetMinimum', 'widgetMaximum', 'widgetNormal', 'widgetClose'):
            widget = QWidget(self)
            widget.setMinimumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            widget.setMaximumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            widget.setObjectName('CTitleBar_%s' % name)
            setattr(self, name, widget)
            layout.addWidget(widget)

        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        # Название
        self.labelTitle = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelTitle.setObjectName('CTitleBar_labelTitle')
        layout.addWidget(self.labelTitle)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        # Свернуть, развернуть, восстановить, кнопкa закрыть
        for name, text in (('buttonMinimum', '0'), ('buttonMaximum', '1'),
                           ('buttonNormal', '2'), ('buttonClose', 'r')):
            button = QPushButton(text, self, font=QFont('Webdings'))
            button.setMinimumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            button.setMaximumSize(self.Radius, self.Radius)
            button.setObjectName('CTitleBar_%s' % name)
            setattr(self, name, button)
            layout.addWidget(button)


class TestCTitleBarBase:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestCTitleBarBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(1000, 600)

        # Установите прозрачность фона
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Установите без границ
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        # Добавить пользовательскую строку заголовка
        layout.addWidget(CTitleBar(self, title='Custom TitleBar.'))

        # нижний Widget
        self.widget = QWidget(self, objectName='bottomWidget')
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # это ваш код :)
        # +++ вот ваше приложение !!!
        self.mainWindow = MainWindow()
        box = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # +++ вот ваше приложение !!!
        box.addWidget(self.mainWindow)


class TestCTitleBarWidget(QWidget, TestCTitleBarBase):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    import cgitb
    sys.excepthook = cgitb.enable(1, None, 5, '')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Style)
    w = TestCTitleBarWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Главное окно')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция изменения размеров модифицированного окна курсором:

```
...
    sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)                # !!! +++
    sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818") # <-попробуйте убрать эту строку
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(                          # !!! +++
        sizeGrip, 
        1, 0, 1, 1, 
        QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
    ) 
...
```

Движение окна по экрану за титульный бар:

```
...
        self.offset_title_bar = False
        ...
        
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)                       # +++ !!!
        ...
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):                                   # +++ !!!
        if self.label_title is obj:    
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.offset_title_bar = True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:  
                self.offset_title_bar = False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
    ...    

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь двигает окно """
        if self.isMaximized():
            # Не двигается при максимизации
            return
            
# !!! self.offset_title_bar
#        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        if   self.offset is not None and \
             event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and \
             self.offset_title_bar:                               # +++ offset_title_bar
             
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.offset)
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.clicks = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)                        # (800, 500)
        self.resize(800, 400)                                # (1200, 700)
        
        # Скрытие стандартной шапки (Без границ)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # Прозрачность окна (WA_TranslucentBackground - прозрачный фон)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Прозрачность
        # self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)
        # Появление виджета в месте курсора
        # self.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        
        self.offset = None
        self.offset_title_bar = False                            # +++ offset_title_bar

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.content)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0) 
        self.label_content = QLabel('Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)
        
        sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)                # !!! +++
        sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818") # <-попробуйте убрать эту строку
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(                          # !!! +++
            sizeGrip, 
            1, 0, 1, 1, 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
        )        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    

        # left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)
        # self.left_bar.setLineWidth(3) # Понятия не имею что это, тени нет в любом случае

# title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0) 

        self.label_title = QLabel('Title_bar', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
# !!!        
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)                       # +++ !!!
        
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    

        # min_button
        self.min_button = QPushButton()
        self.min_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.min_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.min_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.min_button.clicked.connect(self.turn_window)

        # max_button
        self.max_button = QPushButton()
        self.max_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.max_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.max_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.max_button.clicked.connect(self.expand_window)

        # close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        # menu_button
        self.menu_button = QPushButton()
        self.menu_button.setText("")
        self.menu_button.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.menu_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.menu_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle)

        # page_1_button
        self.page_1_button = QPushButton()
        self.page_1_button.setText("")
        self.page_1_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.page_1_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

        self.chek_activ_1 = QFrame()
        self.chek_activ_1.setMaximumWidth(10)
        # self.chek_activ_1.setMinimumWidth(5)
        self.chek_activ_1.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        # page_2_button
        self.page_2_button = QPushButton()
        self.page_2_button.setText("")
        self.page_2_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.page_2_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

        self.chek_activ_2 = QFrame()
        self.chek_activ_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.chek_activ_2.setMaximumWidth(0)
        # self.chek_activ_2.setMinimumWidth(5)
        self.chek_activ_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.min_button, 0, 1)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.max_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.layout_menu_0 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_0.addWidget(self.menu_button)
        self.layout_menu_0.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_0.setSpacing(0)

        self.layout_menu_1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_1.addWidget(self.chek_activ_1)
        self.layout_menu_1.addWidget(self.page_1_button)
        self.layout_menu_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_1.setSpacing(0)

        self.layout_menu_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_menu_2.addWidget(self.chek_activ_2)
        self.layout_menu_2.addWidget(self.page_2_button)
        self.layout_menu_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout_menu_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_0)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_1)
        self.vbox_1.addLayout(self.layout_menu_2)
        self.vbox_1.addStretch()
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.content)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):                                   # +++ !!!
        if self.label_title is obj:    
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.offset_title_bar = True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:  
                self.offset_title_bar = False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def turn_window(self):
        self.showMinimized()

    def expand_window(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.max_button.setIcon(
                QIcon("Ok.png"))
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.max_button.setIcon(
                QIcon("Ok.png"))
            self.showMaximized()
            self.right_bar.setStyleSheet('''''')

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Координаты записи нажатия мышью """
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.offset = event.pos()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь двигает окно """
        if self.isMaximized():
            # Не двигается при максимизации
            return
            
# !!! self.offset_title_bar
#        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        if   self.offset is not None and \
             event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and \
             self.offset_title_bar:                               # +++ offset_title_bar
             
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.offset)
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Мышь отпущена, удалить координаты
        :param event:
        """
        self.offset = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def toggle(self):
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.left_bar, b"minimumWidth")
        self.animation.setDuration(900)
        if self.left_bar.width() == 50:
            self.animation.setStartValue(50)
            self.animation.setEndValue(280)
            self.page_1_button.setText("Page 1")
            self.page_1_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
            self.page_2_button.setText("Page 2")
            self.page_2_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        else:
            self.animation.setStartValue(280)
            self.animation.setEndValue(50)
            self.page_1_button.setText("")
            self.page_1_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
            self.page_2_button.setText("")
            self.page_2_button.setIcon(
                QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutCubic)
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо. А я думал что в функции mouseMoveEvent, нужно каким то образом родителя добавить. Не сам класс, а отдельный виджет.

Comment: @PandaStock пожалуйста. Можно по разному.

Comment: Не сразу заметил и удивило. А каким образом sizeGrip скрывается при максимальном развёрнутом окне? У QSizeGrip это встроенная в библиотеку функция?

Comment: @PandaStock   На некоторых платформах ручка размера автоматически скрывается, когда окно отображается в полноэкранном или развернутом виде. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html#details