# Изменение оконной рамки в pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

Сразу извиняюсь за плохой вопрос. Подскажите как можно поменять оформление стандартной оконной рамки в PyQt . До сих пор не нашел нормального гайда касательно этого вопроса.

Речь идёт вот об этом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сколько угодно, пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855760/ и т.д. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+Qt.FramelessWindowHint

Comment: @S.Nick моей благодарности нет предела

Comment: @S.Nick правда есть одна проблема такая рамка плохо отображается при изменении размера окна (её очень сильно дергает)

Comment: и я так понимаю это работает только если главное окно у меня ```QWidget```

Comment: если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.