# QMainWindow в качестве виджета

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Возможно ли таким способом использовать вместо `QWidget` использовать `QMainWindow`.

Я хочу использовать кастомный оконный менеджер, но как я понимаю класс `FramelessWindow` не может  использовать `w.setWidget(MainWindow(MainWindow))`

файл **main.py**

```
from PySide6 import QtGui
from TextEditorUI import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from TextEditorUI import Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize
from TextEditorWindowstyle import FramelessWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.curFile = ''
        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.createStatusBar()

        self.textEdit.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.documentWasModified)

        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.settings = QSettings('Matewriter', 'Matewriter')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit)
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(self.save)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open)
        self.newfile_action.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.saveas_action.triggered.connect(self.saveAs)
        self.open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.newfile_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        # Конфиги окна
        windowScreenGeometry = self.settings.value("windowScreenGeometry")
        windowScreenState = self.settings.value("windowScreenState")
        if windowScreenGeometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(windowScreenGeometry)

        else:
            self.resize(600)

        if windowScreenState:
            self.restoreState(windowScreenState)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenGeometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenState", self.saveState())
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def newFile(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.textEdit.clear()
            self.setCurrentFile('')

    def open(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
            if fileName:
                self.loadFile(fileName)

    def save(self):
        if self.curFile:
            return self.saveFile(self.curFile)

        return self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        if fileName:
            return self.saveFile(fileName)

        return False

    def documentWasModified(self):
        self.setWindowModified(self.textEdit.document().isModified())

    def createStatusBar(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
        size = settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400))
        self.resize(size)
        self.move(pos)

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
        settings.setValue("size", self.size())

    def maybeSave(self):
        if self.textEdit.document().isModified():
            ret = QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                      "The document has been modified.\nDo you want to save "
                                      "your changes?",
                                      QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel)

            if ret == QMessageBox.Save:
                return self.save()

            if ret == QMessageBox.Cancel:
                return False

        return True

    def loadFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot read file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return

        inf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(inf.readAll())
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File loaded", 2000)

    def saveFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.WriteOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return False

        outf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        outf << self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File saved", 2000)
        return True

    def setCurrentFile(self, fileName):
        self.curFile = fileName
        self.textEdit.document().setModified(False)
        self.setWindowModified(False)

        if self.curFile:
            shownName = self.strippedName(self.curFile)
        else:
            shownName = 'untitled.txt'

        self.setWindowTitle(" %s[*] - MateWriter" % shownName)

    def strippedName(self, fullFileName):
        return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Тестовая строка заголовка')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Qt.ico'))
    w.setWidget(MainWindow(MainWindow))  # Добавить свое окно
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**FramelessWindow.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide6.QtCore    import Qt, pyqtSignal, QPoint
from PySide.QtGui     import QFont, QEnterEvent, QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PySide.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QPushButton)


# Created on 2018年4月30日
# author: Irony
# site: https://github.com/892768447
# email: 892768447@qq.com
# file: FramelessWindow
# description:
__Author__ = """By: Irony
QQ: 892768447
Email: 892768447@qq.com"""
__Copyright__ = 'Copyright (c) 2018 Irony'
__Version__ = 1.0


class TitleBar(QWidget):

    # Сигнал минимизации окна
    windowMinimumed = pyqtSignal()
    # увеличить максимальный сигнал окна
    windowMaximumed = pyqtSignal()
    # сигнал восстановления окна
    windowNormaled = pyqtSignal()
    # сигнал закрытия окна
    windowClosed = pyqtSignal()
    # Окно мобильных
    windowMoved = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    # Сигнал Своя Кнопка +++
    signalButtonMy = pyqtSignal()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Поддержка настройки фона qss
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.mPos     = None
        self.iconSize = 20                       # Размер значка по умолчанию

        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # макет
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # значок окна
        self.iconLabel = QLabel(self)
#         self.iconLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)

        # название окна
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.titleLabel.setMargin(2)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)

        # Средний телескопический бар  
        layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        # Использовать шрифты Webdings для отображения значков
        font = self.font() or QFont()
        font.setFamily('Webdings')


        # Своя Кнопка ++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
        self.buttonMy = QPushButton(
            '@', self, clicked=self.showButtonMy, font=font, objectName='buttonMy')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMy)


        # Свернуть кнопку
        self.buttonMinimum = QPushButton(
            '0', self, clicked=self.windowMinimumed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonMinimum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum)

        # Кнопка Max / restore
        self.buttonMaximum = QPushButton(
            '1', self, clicked=self.showMaximized, font=font, objectName='buttonMaximum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum)

        # Кнопка закрытия
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.windowClosed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonClose')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        # начальная высота
        self.setHeight()

    # +++ Вызывается по нажатию кнопки buttonMy
    def showButtonMy(self):  
        print("Своя Кнопка ")  
        self.signalButtonMy.emit()

    def showMaximized(self):
        if self.buttonMaximum.text() == '1':
            # Максимизировать
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('2')
            self.windowMaximumed.emit()
        else:  # Восстановить
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('1')
            self.windowNormaled.emit()

    def setHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
        # Задайте размер правой кнопки  ?
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMaximumSize(height, height)

        self.buttonMy.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMy.setMaximumSize(height, height)

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ Установить заголовок """
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)

    def setIcon(self, icon):
        """ настройки значокa """
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(self.iconSize, self.iconSize))

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установить размер значка """
        self.iconSize = size

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super(TitleBar, self).enterEvent(event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super(TitleBar, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        self.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        self.mPos = None
        event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            self.windowMoved.emit(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self.mPos))
        event.accept()


# Перечислить верхнюю левую, нижнюю правую и четыре неподвижные точки
Left, Top, Right, Bottom, LeftTop, RightTop, LeftBottom, RightBottom = range(8)


class FramelessWindow(QWidget):

    # Четыре периметра
    Margins = 5

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FramelessWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pressed  = False
        self.Direction = None

        # Фон прозрачный
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Нет границы
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # Отслеживание мыши
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # макет
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        # Зарезервировать границы для изменения размера окна без полей
        layout.setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)
        # Панель заголовка
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)

        # слот сигнала
        self.titleBar.windowMinimumed.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.titleBar.windowMaximumed.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.titleBar.windowNormaled.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.titleBar.windowClosed.connect(self.close)
        self.titleBar.windowMoved.connect(self.move)
        self.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setTitle)
        self.windowIconChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setIcon)

    def setTitleBarHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.titleBar.setHeight(height)

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установка размера значка """
        self.titleBar.setIconSize(size)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        """ Настройте свои собственные элементы управления """
        if hasattr(self, '_widget'):
            return
        self._widget = widget
        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self._widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self._widget.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self._widget.setPalette(palette)
        self._widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._widget)

    def move(self, pos):
        if self.windowState() == Qt.WindowMaximized or self.windowState() == Qt.WindowFullScreen:
            # Максимизировать или полноэкранный режим не допускается
            return
        super(FramelessWindow, self).move(pos)

    def showMaximized(self):
        """ Чтобы максимизировать, удалите верхнюю, нижнюю, левую и правую границы. 
            Если вы не удалите его, в пограничной области будут пробелы. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showMaximized()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def showNormal(self):
        """ Восстановить, сохранить верхнюю и нижнюю левую и правую границы, 
            иначе нет границы, которую нельзя отрегулировать """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showNormal()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ Фильтр событий, используемый для решения мыши в других элементах 
            управления и восстановления стандартного стиля мыши """
        if isinstance(event, QEnterEvent):
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        return super(FramelessWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """ Поскольку это полностью прозрачное фоновое окно, жесткая для поиска 
            граница с прозрачностью 1 рисуется в событии перерисовывания, чтобы отрегулировать размер окна. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1), 2 * self.Margins))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._mpos = event.pos()
            self._pressed = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._pressed = False
        self.Direction = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие перемещения мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        pos = event.pos()
        xPos, yPos = pos.x(), pos.y()
        wm, hm = self.width() - self.Margins, self.height() - self.Margins
        if self.isMaximized() or self.isFullScreen():
            self.Direction = None
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            return
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self._pressed:
            self._resizeWidget(pos)
            return
        if xPos <= self.Margins and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # Верхний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # Нижний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # верхний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif xPos <= self.Margins and hm <= yPos:
            # Нижний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif 0 <= xPos <= self.Margins and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Влево
            self.Direction = Left
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Право
            self.Direction = Right
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and 0 <= yPos <= self.Margins:
            # выше
            self.Direction = Top
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # ниже
            self.Direction = Bottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)

    def _resizeWidget(self, pos):
        """ Отрегулируйте размер окна """
        if self.Direction == None:
            return
        mpos = pos - self._mpos
        xPos, yPos = mpos.x(), mpos.y()
        geometry = self.geometry()
        x, y, w, h = geometry.x(), geometry.y(), geometry.width(), geometry.height()
        if self.Direction == LeftTop:          # Верхний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
        elif self.Direction == RightBottom:    # Нижний правый угол
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
        elif self.Direction == RightTop:       # верхний правый угол
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos.setX(pos.x())
        elif self.Direction == LeftBottom:     # Нижний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos.setY(pos.y())
        elif self.Direction == Left:            # Влево
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Right:           # Право
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Top:             # выше
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Bottom:          # ниже
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
```

**TextEditorUI.py**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 580)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.open_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_action.setObjectName(u"open_action")
        self.newfile_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.newfile_action.setObjectName(u"newfile_action")
        self.save_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.save_action.setObjectName(u"save_action")
        self.saveas_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.saveas_action.setObjectName(u"saveas_action")
        self.exit_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.exit_action.setObjectName(u"exit_action")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"alternate-background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 762, 22))
        self.menu = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName(u"menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.newfile_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.saveas_action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Matewriter", None))
        self.open_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.newfile_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439", None))
        self.save_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.saveas_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043a\u0430\u043a...", None))
        self.exit_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.textEdit.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.menu.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Вот сама ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите модуль `TextEditorUI.py` и расскажите лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMainWindow` наследуется от `QWidget` и имеет некоторые дополнительные удобности для оформления окна приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не отслеживал изменения, которые вы внесли, а только подправил две строки, которые выдавали ошибки.

```
'''
from PySide6 import QtGui
from TextEditorUI import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from TextEditorUI import Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize
from TextEditorWindowstyle import FramelessWindow
'''

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1268642_TextEditorWindowstyle import FramelessWindow

#from TextEditorUI import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 580)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.open_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_action.setObjectName(u"open_action")
        self.newfile_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.newfile_action.setObjectName(u"newfile_action")
        self.save_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.save_action.setObjectName(u"save_action")
        self.saveas_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.saveas_action.setObjectName(u"saveas_action")
        self.exit_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.exit_action.setObjectName(u"exit_action")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"alternate-background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 762, 22))
        self.menu = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName(u"menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.newfile_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.saveas_action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Matewriter", None))
        self.open_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.newfile_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439", None))
        self.save_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.saveas_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043a\u0430\u043a...", None))
        self.exit_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.textEdit.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.menu.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b", None))
    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.curFile = ''
        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.createStatusBar()

        self.textEdit.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.documentWasModified)

        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.settings = QSettings('Matewriter', 'Matewriter')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit)
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(self.save)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open)
        self.newfile_action.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.saveas_action.triggered.connect(self.saveAs)
        self.open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.newfile_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        # Конфиги окна
        windowScreenGeometry = self.settings.value("windowScreenGeometry")
        windowScreenState = self.settings.value("windowScreenState")
        if windowScreenGeometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(windowScreenGeometry)

        else:
#            self.resize(600)
            self.resize(600, 600)                                              # !!!

        if windowScreenState:
            self.restoreState(windowScreenState)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenGeometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenState", self.saveState())
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def newFile(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.textEdit.clear()
            self.setCurrentFile('')

    def open(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
            if fileName:
                self.loadFile(fileName)

    def save(self):
        if self.curFile:
            return self.saveFile(self.curFile)

        return self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        if fileName:
            return self.saveFile(fileName)

        return False

    def documentWasModified(self):
        self.setWindowModified(self.textEdit.document().isModified())

    def createStatusBar(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
        size = settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400))
        self.resize(size)
        self.move(pos)

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
        settings.setValue("size", self.size())

    def maybeSave(self):
        if self.textEdit.document().isModified():
            ret = QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                      "The document has been modified.\nDo you want to save "
                                      "your changes?",
                                      QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel)

            if ret == QMessageBox.Save:
                return self.save()

            if ret == QMessageBox.Cancel:
                return False

        return True

    def loadFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot read file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return

        inf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(inf.readAll())
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File loaded", 2000)

    def saveFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.WriteOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return False

        outf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        outf << self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File saved", 2000)
        return True

    def setCurrentFile(self, fileName):
        self.curFile = fileName
        self.textEdit.document().setModified(False)
        self.setWindowModified(False)

        if self.curFile:
            shownName = self.strippedName(self.curFile)
        else:
            shownName = 'untitled.txt'

        self.setWindowTitle(" %s[*] - MateWriter" % shownName)

    def strippedName(self, fullFileName):
        return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Тестовая строка заголовка')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Qt.ico'))
    
#    w.setWidget(MainWindow(MainWindow))       # Добавить свое окно
    w.setWidget(MainWindow())                                                 # !!!
    
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хотел уточнить, у меня этот код создает не цельное окно как у вас, а делает пробел  между окном и виджетом. Вот пример https://prnt.sc/119qets

Comment: @Farodin это уже другой вопрос. Попробуйте добавить строку `app.setStyle('Fusion')` после строки `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` или другие стили доступные вам.

Comment: к сожалению смена стиля не даёт эффекта , я так понимаю у вас эта проблема не наблюдается?

Comment: @Farodin отметьте на изображении то, что у вас не так. И скажите, вы запускаете мой пример или что?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11a2ifo вот эта полоса упорно не хочет пропадать. Запускал код изложенный мной выше с вашими поправками

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267887/Изменение-оконной-рамки-в-pyqt?noredirect=1#comment2230619_1267887 пример изложенный вами в этой стать запускается с таким же результатом

Comment: @Farodin нет, так не пойдет, что у вас происходит с примером, который я предоставил в ответе?

Comment: @Farodin  у вас `PySide6` ?

Comment: да Pyside6, с вашим кодом только с импортами Pyside вот такой результат https://prnt.sc/11a38lj

Comment: @Farodin  app.setStyle('Fusion') - установили?

Comment: да, не помогает

Comment: @Farodin  Sorry, у меня не установлен ни `Pyside`  , ни `Pyside6`.  Проверить не могу.

Comment: проверил на PyQt  там такой проблемы не наблюдаются

Comment: @Farodin закройте вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051263/different-result-using-pyqt5-and-pyside6 иначе пострадает и последний вопрос

Comment: закрыл, спасибо

Comment: @ S. Nick Если вам интересно, то решение такое                                                                                         
  The reason is that the named arguments to QVBoxLayout are not supported

`layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)`
The property needs to be set by calling the setter.

`layout = QVBoxLayout(self)`
        `layout.setSpacing(0)`